# Ubuntu: sound card enumeration

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I can't find an article about Ubuntu 21.04's way to enumerate sound cards. Does anyone know how that happens?

I have two sound cards in the computer, but only one shows up in jack2. Meanwhile, the onboard sound chip is disabled (do I also need to disable it logically? How?) and still shows up in Jack2 instead of the second card.

Too, when I try to configure jack for the second card, jack stubbornly shows the onboard chip, but with (disconnected) as a comment.

Paprefs doesn't show any hardware, just a checkbox that when checked is supposed to create a virtual card for all of the present cards. I don't see  that happening anywhere.

Comment: that got little to do with Ubuntu: Sound cards are just USB, Firewire, PCIe devices, and your kernel needs to detect them. So, a) what sound cards, b) how are they attached, c) does your kernel find them?

Comment: Thank you, Marcus. The Kernel apparently finds at least one card, b/c I have sound. I look for them via aplay -l which does NOT show the onboard sound chip and the two cards labeled DX,0 and DX_1,0. They are PCIEs. I can send you screenshots. Jack's backend is ALSA. The main Q here is: why does the onboard chip show up in Jack instead of the second DX card. aplay doesn't detect it, but it shows up in Jack.
Thanks again, John.s

Comment: TO clarify, aplay labels the cards DX,0 and DX_1,0. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone, please? Thx, John.

Comment: Here us what $cat /proc/asound/cards finds:

Comment: Here us what $cat /proc/asound/cards finds: 0 [DX]: AV200-Xonar DX ASUS Virtuoso 100 at 0xe000, irq 16. The second card is found having the same data, except that it's at 0xc000, irq 19. As I wrote before, aplay labels them differently: DX,0 and DX_1,0.